# Can only see half of folder screen?

Tags: macos, finder, screen

My Finder folders today have a line beside the folders

Since the view is half blank, I have to move the line over before I can view the rest.

Can anyone help a girl out?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

**View** → **Show Preview** ⇧⌘P / **Hide Preview** ⇧⌘P toggles the pane on the right.

You can alternatively…

- drag the edge of the window right to make the window bigger so you can see more contents without hiding the preview pane.
- choose View → Arrange By to choose an arrangement of items — any arrangement will automatically place the folder contents within the view with only vertical scrolling.